# Is it possible to reopen closed NetConnection?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an application that records camera and mic of users and saves it on Adobe Media Server.

The application itself works fine, but recently, I started having many cases in which the audio and video was being cut, and turns out that Flash is disconnecting from the server every once and while.

Due to how the application was designed, every time it detects a disconnection (`NetConnection.Connect.Closed`) that was not triggered by the user, it opens a new connections and starts recording again (using the same target file).

The problem with this workflow, is that during the period where there is no connection, nothing is recorded, causing a cut effect similar to what Youtube vloggers do.

Since I cannot migrate a stream from one connection to the other, I was thinking in calling `netconnection.connect(url)` to the same URL, but when I did it, nothing happened, no `NetStatus` event is triggered.

Is it possible to resume an interrupted recording without having to ask the user to patiently wait while a new connection is opened?

P.S.: This started be an issue recently on IE and Edge, every other browser works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to reopen the connection, but [that must be done outside the `NetStatus` event scope](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetConnection.html#connect()).

You can either use `setTimeout(function(){reconnect()}, 100)` or trigger another event that will do the reconnection.